# BCP utility:“Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'”

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, etl, bcp

I moved a SQL Agent job from a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance to a 2016 instance. The job called a PowerShell script which in turn called bcp.exe. After moving the job, I receive this error:

> Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'.

The command did not change, only the location of the job and version of the instance.

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table]" queryout "\\filerepository\ftp\text_file.txt" -T -c -t"|" -S"ServerName" -d"MyDB"
```

Also, I ran this locally using the 2012 bcp.exe and received the same error. When I compare the books online article for the bcp utility, I do not see any changes which would affect the syntax of this command.

I would appreciate any advice.

**Updated: The PowerShell Script**

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
$serverInstance = "Server"
$databaseName = "DB"


# construct query
$query = @"
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Table]
"@

$query = $query -replace "`n|`r|`t"," "

# output results
$extractPath = "\\filerepository\ftp\"
$fileName = "CTBRI_$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd")_text_file.txt"
$path = Join-Path $extractPath $fileName;

$cmd = "`"$query`" queryout `"$path`" -T -c -t`"|`" -S`"$serverInstance`" -d`"$databaseName`""

bcp $cmd

if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
{
    throw "bcp did not exit with a success code of 0. Hopefully there are more detailed messages above."
}
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is with the PowerShell script.  Add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Just tested the BCP syntax on a 2016 box and works for me. Works in powershell as well.

Comment: I updated the post with the PowerShell script.

Comment: I was able to copy & paste the command out and it worked. Now the question is how the cmd is getting mangled so that it fails.

Comment: These are of the PowerShell step type in SQL Agent which means that each is using SQLPS.exe and they are of different versions. I am trying to figure out how the string might be different between them.

Comment: @SQLHammer specify the full `bcp.exe` path. It will work. I have seen cases wherein if you do `bcp /?` you will not see the bcp output has an `in or out` command due to old bcp env. variable.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. However, using the full path did not change the symptoms.

Answer (score 2):

Same version of Powershell on the servers/vms hosting SQL Server 2008R2, 2012, and 2016?

A parsing error that removes the double quotes around the query would result in this error.